# Using predict with PCR in R

Tags: r, partial-least-squares

I'm trying to follow the documentation on the pcr method in R

So I do the following

```
library(pls)
data(yarn)
# Note 
#   the yarn data frame has 28 rows
#   out of which 21 are used for training
#   and 7 used for testing
yarn.pcr <- pcr(density ~ NIR, data=yarn,validation = "CV", subset=yarn$Train)
    # ok I ask predict to use components 1 through 6 to predict 
    pred.pcr <- predict(yarn.pcr, ncomp = 1:6, newdata=yarn,subset=!yarn$Train)
```

however I'm not quite sure how to use the resulting object from the predict method pred.pcr.

I would have expected to get 7 values in the pred.pcr object However I have something like

```
> length(pred.pcr)
[1] 168
```

So I'm a bit confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examining `dim(pred.pcr)` gives `[1] 28  1  6`, so it's really using all of the data.

Looking at `class(yarn.pcr)` gives `"mvr"`, so `predict.mvr` is being called and `?predict.mvr` shows that it doesn't have a `subset` argument, only a `newdata` argument.

Therefore the appropriate way to call it is as

```
pred.pcr <- predict(yarn.pcr, ncomp = 1:6, newdata=subset(yarn, !train))
```

In fact, this is in the examples in the documentation for `?predict.mvr`.

Comment: thanks -- I tried it an it seemed to work -- the thing I still don't understand is that how do I interpret the output -- I have six set's output each with the heading , , 1 comps , , 2 comps , , 3 comps , , 4 comps , , 5 comps , , 6 comps